# Is there a standard for testing d3 interactions in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, svg, d3.js

Right now I'm trying to test click interactions with d3 generated svg elements:

```
test('should not be able to scroll past extents', function() {
  expect(2);

  visit('/links');
  fillIn('.search input', 'list');
  click('.selectable.active');
  andThen(function() {
    var label = find('#xaxis .label').text();
    equal(label, 'oldname');

    // click the svg element
    click('#plot rect.full.bar:first');
    label = find('#xaxis .label').text();

    // assert labelname 
    equal(label, 'newname');
    // is still 'oldname'
  });
});
```

So far this does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it end up changing?  Is the click working, just the find is happening before d3 has responded to the action?

Comment: The click is not registering. The selector is correct, though.

Comment: If you use `find('#plot rect.full.bar:first')` does it return the element?  I know that Ember's click is scoped to elements that live within the scope of the app (which I'd assume this does, but a good test).  Also if you just use $('#plot rect.full.bar:first').click(), does it trigger the name change?

Comment: It does not trigger the name change when i use .click()